# How to repeat background image with css

Tags: html, css

I need repeat as background image gried.png image in welcome.blade.php in My app. I need create class selector file in css folder for this.
this is My welcome.css file in public/css folder

```
.background-image{
    background-image:transparent url("/imgs/grid.png");
    background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

This is my **welcomeblade.php** file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/welcome.css" /> 
<div class="background-image"></div>
```

But this code did not generate any result, how can I fix this?

Comment: Note that the `<link>` tag does not use or need a closing slash.

Answer (score 2):

`transparent` is not a valid value for `background-image`. It's a value for `background-color`.

```
.background-image {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("/imgs/grid.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

should work.

See it here (with a different url for the image): https://jsfiddle.net/h0revzu5/

Comment: In general you can use Chrome's "Developer Tools" to inspect any element with a problem and check the "Styles" tab to see if any of your definitions are invalid and thus being ignored. Just right-click the affected element and choose "Inspect".

Comment: I made the example more complete and included a jsfiddle link. Also note that you must have some content in the div or something to give it height to see the background image. Also check Developer Tools on the Network tab and make sure that the image is being loaded ok. Or visit the url in your browser and make sure it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Just try background-attachment:repeat;

Answer (score 0):

Example of background-repeat:

```css
body {
    background-image: url("https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

OR

Also by default it repeats when you set background,

```css
body {
    background: url("https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png");
  
}
```

Default background-color is `background-color:transparent;`